# Can Python method check if it's being used for assignment?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Suppose I have a method which can return a value, or can just be quickly called to see if I even did get the return value I expected.

```
from pprint import pprint
from my_module import get_data

def quicktest():
    #pseudocode here to illustrate what I want
    if isUsedForAssignment:
        return get_data()
    else:
        pprint(get_data())
```

The idea here being I'm checking this returned data to ensure the structure is correct; however if I don't care about that, I'd rather assign the value. This way I just go into my Python interpreter and type:

```
import thismodule as thism
thism.quicktest()
```

…as opposed to some way of doing it where I'm continually importing pprint just to see my data structure correctly.

This is maybe a slightly pedantic example, but it prompted the question in me as to whether or not a method can tell if it's being used to assign a value or just to be called straight-up.

Comment: My gut instinct is "no". A method call is a method call, the assignment occurs after it's over.

Comment: A less magical solution would be using an interpreter that prettyprints result values. (I believe IPython might.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Technically* you could inspect the parent frame's bytecode or source code. But this is not only incredibly fragile and hacky and complicated, it's also a surefire way to indicate that you're doing something wrong<sup>TM</sup>. Just don't do that. Write the method to always simply return the value, and do the printing at the call site. Alternatively, if the printing is nontrivial, write a separate method to do the printing.

Comment: Yeah, over the weekend I started to feel like it was not worth the effort and even if one *could* do this, one wouldn't necessarily want to. Thanks